# Static Banner Admob for Android

Tags: admob

I want to put a static banner from Admob in my application for Android but I don't know how. The problem is that when I begin a new Activity in the application, the banner dissapear and if I want to show a banner in the new activity I have to create a new banner in that activity. I want to know how I can show the same banner in all the activities from the application.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

1) Make a MyAdActivity class that all of your Activity classes extend.

public class MyAdActivity extends Activity {

```
AdView mAdView=null;

protected void onPause() {
    if (mAdView != null) mAdView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mAdView != null) mAdView.resume();
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mAdView != null) mAdView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void setUpAndLoadAd(int xmlId, int layoutId, boolean bottom) {

            // The first argument is the name of the XML file for this activity
            // The second argument is the id for the main layout window of the activity
            //    (generally in the xml file named in the first argument)
            // The third argument is just a boolean that says,
            //              "I want the ad to go on the bottom" (true)
            //      ... or  "I want the ad to go on the top" (false)    

    int topOrBottom;

    if (xmlId != 0) setContentView(xmlId); // if you setContentView before
                                                   // you called setUpAndLoadAd, then
                                                   // you can pass a 0 to this method 
                                                   // and it won't get called again

    // Save the pointer to the BannerAdView so we can pause, resume
    // and destroy it with the activity that started it.
    mAdView = new AdView(getBaseContext());
    mAdView.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
    mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(layoutId);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    if (bottom) topOrBottom = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM;
    else topOrBottom = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP;

    params.addRule(topOrBottom);
    layout.addView(mAdView, params);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(getResources().getString(R.string.test_device)) // My Galaxy SIII Phone*/
        .build();

    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

}

Then your Activities will look like this:

public class MainActivity extends MyAdActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // put the ad on the bottom (if the last argument is false,
    // the ad will go on the top).
    setUpAndLoadAd(R.layout.activity_main, R.id.main_window, true);

    //Any other code you want to put in your activity goes here.
}
```

}

Then, make sure you identify "ad_id_unit" (that you get from AdMob) and "test_device" (the actual string can be found in the logcat window when you debug with your device) in your strings.xml file.

You need to put the meta-data lines in your Manifest file, but you don't have to declare any special Activity in there because you already listed your activities that are extending the MyAdActivity.  Also, everything for the banner ad is done in code, so you don't need to change your layout xml files in any way, except to make sure there is room at the top or bottom of the layout for the ad.

This type of implementation for ads is not exactly a "static" ad, but it is a simple way of using the same code over and over to add ads to multiple activities in your app.

Comment: where will setContentView go, for the mainActivity?